# How do people in Silicon Valley pronounce "10x" as in a "10x engineer"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I am researching the tech industry in the United States and frequently find the term "10x" developer or engineer, meaning that the worker is respected as being outstanding in their field, in effect contributing "ten times" the normal amount of work a regular employee can do.

For my research I'm wondering whether people in the tech industry have a fixed way of pronouncing this, as in "ten ex" or "ten times" (as in *"ten times the normal engineer"*), or do they switch between both?  Or do they, ~~*gasp*~~ disagree?  If so, to what extent?

My preliminary research suggests a potential lack of consensus, but it's based solely on [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-is-10x-pronounced) with few upvotes and one answer suggesting each pronunciation.  Can someone here help?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it's pronounced **ten-ex**. Usually when it's pronounced differently, it's because the speaker is unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: I concur, I've only ever heard it used by people who know in the form that would pronounce it this way, like an algebra expression 'ten ex'